# Experiences deploying ASP.NET 3.5 web site with charting control

Tags: asp.net, deployment, charts

Has anyone deployed a web site using the 3.5 framework and the Microsoft charting control?

I know this is built into .NET 4.0, but our client isn't ready to move up to the .NET 4.0 yet.

Specifically, do you need to run the chart install on the server to deploy the control, or is there a way to do this in the deployment (such as dropping the System.Web.DataVisualization [sp?] dll into the BIN directory and updating Web.config?

Thanks,
Tim

EDIT:
I want to add we're using VS 2010 as our IDE...has anyone used the chart control while targeting the 3.5 .NET framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used the controls myself so I don't now what major differences there are between versions, if any, but you can try using the [.NET 3.5 version of the charting controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c).

Edit: You should be able to add the .NET 3.5 control to the VS 2010 Toolbox manually, if it isn't added automatically using the instructions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165355.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Frazell, I've looked into the 3.5 version. The problem is the toolbox support is for Visual Studio 2008. I'm on Studio 2010 and when I target the 4.0 version of the framework, the Chart appears in the toolbox under Data.

I don't know if installing the 3.5 version will do anything to VS 2010 or not. (I doubt it, since I still have VS2008 installed)

Comment: @Tim you should be able to add the .NET 3.5 version to your VS 2010 Toolbox (I haven't tested, but can't see why it wouldn't work).

Comment: Ugh - I found this on Microsoft's site:

`Visual Studio hides custom Web server controls in the Toolbox that do not apply to the currently targeted version of the .NET Framework. If multiple versions of a custom Web server control are installed, Visual Studio hides all but the most current version. To see all versions, you can right-click the Toolbox and select Show All.`

It looks like VS2010 won't show the charting components unless we target the 4.0 framework.

If anyone else has a different experience, I'm curious to hear whether this can even be done.